# In a quantum state with 50-50% probability, can the outcome ever be determined with any law or logic? Or should it always be a random value?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, superposition

Please help me here.

If the probability is 50-50%, the outcome can only be a random one.
And a random outcome can never be determined by any laws or rules of physics. And if I'm not wrong, quantum state of superposition is a result of quantum laws not being able to make a random selection.

Answer (score 2):

Within the framework of quantum theory, the presence of true randomness is in fact one of the highlights.

Just keep in mind that quantum theory has two big aspects in this regard:

- The evolution of the wave function is completely deterministic, as it's described by the Schrödinger equation.
- The phenomena called "collapse of the wave function", however, is not. Whether it's triggered by natural evolution (interacting with the environment) or due to a experimental measurement, that's where randomness happens.

If you want to study what physicists have been trying to test whether or not there's true randomness, see Bells' inequalities and the experiments that have been performed about it in the past 40 years.

Of course, there's also some research on alternative visions that manage to restore complete determinism, but so far they haven't come up with complete, consistent and useful answers.